# How to disable user's input while loading page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a heavy-jquerized page with some links, various user inputs and such.

I use jquery, with actions defined in a

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  ....
} );
```

block.

But while the page is loading (or, even worse - reloading), and a user clicks a link, the `href` action from it is triggered, as the javascript isn't loaded / active yet.

I wanted to block it somehow. One way that came to my mind is to put a transparent div over whole document, that would receive the click events instead of the layer below it. Then, in my `.ready` function in javascript, I could hide that div making it possible to use the page.

Is it a good practice? Or should I try some different approach?

Comment: you can give a try to that approach

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) (which probably usew the same or similar idea behind the scenes).

Comment: Yes, do not make it yourself. IE6 does not play nice with fixed positioned div elements and it requires a lot of hacks to get it working.

Comment: I think BlockUI relies on DOMLoaded as well, so it wouldn't server the issue - blocking while page loads

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want your links to act like links (ie their `href` is never meant to followed), why make them links in the first place? You'd be better served by making your clickable elements a `div` or `span` (something without a default action), and attaching the click handler as per normal.

I'd really advise against blocking the ui with a div - it seems the entirely wrong approach, making the page non-functional to someone with JS disabled, as well as blocking other common tasks like copying text.

---

In light of the clarification, to block the UI only if JS is enabled, but not yet loaded, I'd suggest the following.

HTML (first thing after `body`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div id="UIBlocker">Please wait while we load...</div>')</script>
```

CSS:

```
#UIBlocker 
{ 
    position: fixed; /* or absolute, for IE6 */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Or, if you prefer not to use `document.write`, leave the UIBlocker `div` as straight HTML at the top of `body`, but have the following in `head`

HTML:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #UIBlocker { display: none !important; }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

This will ensure it does not block for non-JS enabled browsers

Comment: I try to get as much functionality as possible when javascript is disabled. Having links acting like links makes it work there...

Comment: So you want the page functional as-is, but blocked only if JS is enabled but not yet loaded?

Comment: exactly... that's what I'd want (well, if it won't be possible, i'll screw the compatibility with non-js clients)

Comment: Also, having links as links makes it possible to use non-keyboard browsing. I myself sometimes use addons that highlight me the links on page and make them selectable by typing a number on keyboard...

Comment: Ok, in that case, please refer to my amended answer

Answer (score 2):

A transparent `div` could work, assuming it’s positioned above everything. (I’m never quite clear how visible an element has to be to receive click events.)

You might want to make the `div` visible though; it could be equally confusing for visitors if they can see everything on the page, but not click it.

You’ll probably need to use JavaScript to make the `div` as tall as the page though.

Answer (score 1):

The overlay DIV should work. Another option would be to place all the content inside a hidden container `visibility: hidden` then toggle to `visible` as the last `$(document).ready` statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it yourself javascript isn't loaded yet. Maybe the css isn't loaded either.

so something with visual element will not work i think. IF you want to do some with the viaual elements (css) you have to hardcode it in the html node `<tagname style="blabla">`

You could possibly add the href behavious in a later stadium when the js is loaded.

What you get is a `<span>` with a title and this should set the behaviour or something. I used a title, but can be a different attribute.

This doesn't use any jquery, only for loading

```
    $(document).reade(function () {
        relNoFollow();
    });

function relNoFollow() {
    var FakeLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    if( FakeLinks.length > 0 ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < FakeLinks.length; i++ ) {
            if( FakeLinks[i].title.indexOf( 'http://' ) != -1 ) {
                FakeLinks[i].onmouseout     = fakelinkMouseOut;
                FakeLinks[i].onmouseover    = fakelinkMouseOver;
                FakeLinks[i].onclick        = fakelinkClick;
            }
        }
    }
}

function fakelinkMouseOver() {
    this.className = 'fakelink-hover';
}

function fakelinkMouseOut() {
    this.className = 'fakelink';
}

function fakelinkClick() {
    window.location.href = this.title;
}
```